# How can I initialize a NN model to specific weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Apologies in advance for the elementary nature of this question. I don't know how to get started and haven't been able to find any example code.

The following very simple NN will add two numbers.

```
model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()

# -----------------------------------------
# first layer: input layer
# Input layer does not do any processing, so no need to define it.

# -----------------------------------------
# second layer: hidden layer:
model.add(Dense(nbr_hidden_neurons=1, input_dim=2) )  
# No need for an Activation. Just return the value computed.
# model.add(Activation('linear')) # Activation

# -----------------------------------------
# third layer: output layer:
model.add(Dense(output_size=1, input_dim=1))  
# Again, no need for an Activation. Just return the value computed.
# model.add(Activation('linear')) # Activation

return model
```

If all the weights are set to 1 and all the biases set to 0, we will get an exact sum.

My question is what code can I use to set the initial values of the weights and biases?

This is a simple experiment. I want to see what happens if the weights and biases begin training exactly where they should be. I also want to demonstrate that those are correct numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: You will still have to train the model atleast once. Keep the outputs as the sum of the inputs and train the model. After this, save the model using `model.save_weights('weights.h5')` and the next time you define the same architecture and compile the model, don't train it, just use `model.load_weights('weights.h5')`

Answer (score 1):

**use initializer to initialize the weights**

```
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(value = 1) , bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros , input_shape=(2,2))
```

```
dense(tf.random.normal((2,2)))
```

```
dense.weights
```

```
[<tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

Comment: Thanks, When I used the first line, but not any of the rest, the weights and biases were set as intended, but the predictions were all wrong. Please see [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-NSaVil4r_RXgxHk5E_x4KJGC1qm_3ZP). When trained with 200 epochs, the predictions are correct, but the weights and biases are changed. Any thoughts?

Comment: as you start your training the weights and biases are changed w.r.t the loss of the model. During training the loss is back-propagated from the last node to the first node, therefore the weights have been changed.

Comment: Why are the predictions wrong with no training?

Comment: Once the model is trained the weights are no longer the same as it was set initially. May be you want to perform a **Linear Regression** or you want to take the **dot product** between your *training examples* and *weights* but you are applying Dense Layer. Think about it!

Comment: I set the weights and biases and with NO training ran the model on some inputs. After [the run](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-NSaVil4r_RXgxHk5E_x4KJGC1qm_3ZP), the weights and biases were as set, but the predictions were wrong. How could that be?

Comment: Now the [predictions](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-NSaVil4r_RXgxHk5E_x4KJGC1qm_3ZP) are twice what they should be. That seems like progress, but why is the output doubled?

Comment: Finally got the right answers. Had incorrect parameters before.